# Error when benchmarking French datasets constituting the MTEB French leaderboard

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, embedding, mteb

I want to evaluate some french embeddings models using MTEB Semantic Text Similarity (STS) task.
To do this, I took inspiration from this code [run_mteb_french.py](https://github.com/embeddings-benchmark/mteb/blob/main/scripts/run_mteb_french.py)

```
   import logging

   from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
   from mteb import MTEB

   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
   logger = logging.getLogger("main")

   model_name = "dangvantuan/sentence-camembert-large"
   model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)

   TASK_LIST_STS = [
        "SummEvalFr",
        "STSBenchmarkMultilingualSTS",
        "STS22",
        "SICKFr"
    ]
    
    for task in TASK_LIST_STS:
      logger.info(f"Running task: {task}")
      evaluation = MTEB(tasks=[task], task_langs=["fr"]) 
      evaluation.run(model_name, output_folder=f"fr_results/{model_name}")
```

But I got this error:

> Summarization
>
> ```
> - SummEvalFr, p2p
> ```
>
> ERROR:mteb.evaluation.MTEB:Error while evaluating SummEvalFr:
> 'batch_size' is an invalid keyword argument for encode()
>
> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in <cell line: 17>()
> 18   logger.info(f"Running task: {task}")
> 19   evaluation = MTEB(tasks=[task], task_langs=["fr"])
> ---> 20   evaluation.run(model_name, output_folder=f"fr_results/{model_name}")
>
> 4 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mteb/evaluation/evaluators/SummarizationEvaluator.py
> in **call**(self, model)
> 51
> 52         logger.info(f"Encoding {sum(human_lens)} human summaries...")
> ---> 53         embs_human_summaries_all = model.encode(
> 54             [summary for human_summaries in self.human_summaries for summary in human_summaries],
> 55             batch_size=self.batch_size,
>
> TypeError: 'batch_size' is an invalid keyword argument for encode()

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Typo error !
In code, I do `evaluation.run(model_name, output_folder=f"fr_results/{model_name}")`. It's rather `evaluation.run(model, output_folder=f"fr_results/{model_name}")`